# Scrolling text (marquee) in terminal

Tags: ocaml

I wrote an OCaml program that displays a scrolling marquee in the terminal:

[image: Ocaml scrolling marquee]

Code:

```ml
(* Displays moving text in the terminal.
 * Uses VT100 escape sequences.
 * Usage:
 *     ocaml <this-file>
 * *)
#load "unix.cma"

let rec loop max_col curr_col =
    print_string "\x1B[2J";  (* Clear screen. *)
    print_string ("\x1B[1;" ^ (string_of_int curr_col) ^ "H");
    print_string "Hello world!";
    flush stdout;
    Unix.sleepf 0.2;
    if curr_col >= max_col then  (* Start from the beginning. *)
        loop max_col 0
    else
        loop max_col (curr_col + 1)

let () =
    (* Raise Sys.Break on Ctrl-C (SIGINT). *)
    Sys.catch_break true;
    print_string "\x1B[?25l";  (* Hide cursor. *)
    try
        loop 20 0
    with
        Sys.Break -> print_string "\x1B[?25h";  (* Show cursor. *)
```

The code appears to work well, as you can see in the GIF above. I need some advice:

- Did I write the program correctly? I am targeting terminal emulators that support VT100 escape sequences, and I want to make sure that this is portable across terminal emulators.